# Bootstrap modal dialog tabbing in behind page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

When I initialize and show bootstrap modal dialog, all elements on the page behind the dialog and expose mask are still reachable by tab navigation.

[Here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) on official Bootstrap page that is not the case. There is no any specific code for this, just simple modal show.

Any ideas how to disable tabbing behind the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating to [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/), where this is not an issue.